# Eigen3 customization for non-scalar (block) matrices

Tags: c++, matrix, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3

I need a library for block-matrix algebra, where the block-matrix is a sparse matrix storing only references (pointers or wrapper/interface) to dense matrices (blocks). The size (row & cols) of the blocks is variable. I would like to define an algebra over these block matrices preferably with lazy evaluation. Essentially, I would need something like this:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<Eigen::MatrixXd> bm1;
```

or

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<std::shared_ptr<Eigen::MatrixXd>> bm2;
```

My current approach is to use:

```
Eigen::SparseMatrix<Eigen::MatrixXd*> bm3;
```

but I would like to have a class that handles the lifetime of the blocks. Also, I am not really comfortable with the implicit cast `Eigen::MatrixXd*` to `long` in the background -- I guess that is what is happens.

Based on the [Eigen customization description](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicCustomizingEigen.html) it is not clear if this is feasible: the Eigen::SparseMatrixBase does not prefer any non-scalar type.

Question: Should I consider Eigen as an approach to my problem? If yes, how can I get around the problem of non-scalar matrix-element types?

Any comment is much appreciated!

Comment: You are looking for block-sparse matrix - however I dont think Eigen provides that.  This is rather non-trivial object to implement with consistency.  Do you know sparsity pattern ahead of time?  What operations do you require?

Comment: @Anycorn : Indeed, I need a block-sparse matrix algebra library where the size of blocks vary largely from 1x1 to 10k x 10k. I know Eigen doesn't have direct support for this, but I was hoping that it might be possible to "hack" it, and to reuse the sparse storage of Eigen. My problem is that the sparsity pattern changes over time -- blocks appear and disappear. I need +,* operations, pruning etc., I don't need solvers. I wanted to avoid writing a whole new sparse block matrix library, but it seems to be unavoidable since later I'll need MPI support as well.

Comment: Sounds like you have a fairly non-trivial problem, especially with sparse matrix multiplies.  Take a look at tiled array perhaps - https://code.google.com/p/tiledarray/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @Anycorn Thanks for the reference. It is indeed a promising project, but unfortunately not as well-proven as Eigen, Armadillo, PETSc etc. I think I'll need my own solution.